# Accessing a node within a template called from within a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm brand new to XSLT so I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't get it.  I am trying to transform a report outputed into simple xml into a pipe delimited file.  I can't figure out how to access wd:SSN from inside a template that is called from within a for-each.  The xml output from a report looks something like this.

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Company>
      <wd:Company_Code>123</wd:Company_Code>
    </wd:Company>
    <wd:Employee_Last_Name>Smith</wd:Employee_Last_Name>
    <wd:Employee_First_Name>Joe</wd:Employee_First_Name>
    <wd:SSN>123456789</wd:SSN>
    <wd:Street_Address>123 First St</wd:Street_Address>
    <wd:City>Colorado Springs</wd:City>
    <wd:State_Province>CO</wd:State_Province>   
    <wd:ZIP_Code>80927</wd:ZIP_Code>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Company>
      <wd:Company_Code>123</wd:Company_Code>
    </wd:Company>
    <wd:Employee_Last_Name>Smith</wd:Employee_Last_Name>
    <wd:Employee_First_Name>Sally</wd:Employee_First_Name>
    <wd:SSN>123456790</wd:SSN>
    <wd:Street_Address>123 First St</wd:Street_Address>
    <wd:City>Colorado Springs</wd:City>
    <wd:State_Province>CO</wd:State_Province>
    <wd:ZIP_Code>80927</wd:ZIP_Code>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
```

Then my code looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC">

  <!-- Loop thru employee records for Company 123 -->
  <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Company/wd:Company_Code = '123']">
    <xsl:call-template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee"/>      
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Process Company Employee -->
<xsl:template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee">
<!-- EMP Employee Record -->
  <xsl:text>EMP|N|N</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="wd:SSN"/>
  <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="insertNewLine"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the wd:company node in the xml, I updated it to include that node.  The problem I am having is accessing wd:SSN.  When I have it directly in the for-each it works fine.  But since the portion of code for processing an employee is actually 600+ lines and I need to execute that for multiple companies I split it out into the ProcessCompanyEmployee template.  When I do that it doesn't like wd:SSN anymore.  I assume I need to reference the wd:SSN, etc fields a different way, but I don't know what that is.  Does that explain my issue better?

Comment: Ah...I'm reading more.  It sounds like I might need a match pattern in my ProcessCompanyEmployee template to provide the context, but I can't figure out what that should be.  I've tried wd:Report_Entry, I've tried wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry, and neither works.

Comment: What is your expected output? I replaced your *insertNewLine* template which is not defined anywhere in stylesheet for `&#xa;` (newline) and moved `xmlns:wd...` to root tag and no error appeared with pipe delimited output. Unclear what your issue is.

Comment: My xslt code is 5000+ lines long.  I only included the sections of the code pertinent to my issue.  My issue being the reference to wd:SSN inside the ProcessCompanyEmployee template fails.

Comment: Did you place `xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC"` in root tag of xslt?

Comment: I moved it up to the xsl:stylesheet as Daniel suggested below and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the namespace on one xsl:template, but also trying to use it in another xsl:template.

Try moving your xmlns:wd declaration up to the xsl:stylesheet.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <!-- Loop thru employee records for Company 123 -->
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Company/wd:Company_Code = '123']">
      <xsl:call-template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee"/>      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process Company Employee -->
  <xsl:template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee">
    <!-- EMP Employee Record -->
    <xsl:text>EMP|N|N</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:SSN"/>
    <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="insertNewLine"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="insertNewLine">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, since you're using XSLT 2.0, you could not use a prefix at all in your XPath's and add:

```
xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC"
```

to xsl:stylesheet.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
    <!-- Loop thru employee records for Company 123 -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry[Company/Company_Code = '123']">
      <xsl:call-template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee"/>      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process Company Employee -->
  <xsl:template name="ProcessCompanyEmployee">
    <!-- EMP Employee Record -->
    <xsl:text>EMP|N|N</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
    <xsl:text>||</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="insertNewLine"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="insertNewLine">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Daniel!  That solved my problem!  Appreciate it!  I don't know enough to understand your last statement but my code is working so I'm good for now I guess.

Comment: @RDay - You're welcome! I also added an example to illustrate what I was talking about in my last statement. Basically I stripped all `wd:` prefixed from the xpaths and changed `xmlns:wd` on xsl:stylesheet to `xpath-default-namespace`. It makes the XPaths a lot cleaner in larger stylesheets where most of the XPaths point to elements/attributes in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for-each select` you've got `[wd:Company/wd:Company_Code = '123']`, but the XML doesn't contain a `wd:Company` element.

The following template works to transform your XML:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//wd:Report_Entry[wd:Company_Code = '123']">
        <xsl:text>EMP|N|N</xsl:text>
        ...
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:SSN"/>
        ...
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Using your original matches/selects as follows also works:

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Company_Code = '123']">
```

When testing XSLT it helps to reduce use of templates and get it operating to select one element (say SSN), then build back up from there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the wd:company node in the xml, I updated it to include that node. The problem I am having is accessing wd:SSN. When I have it directly in the for-each it works fine. But since the portion of code for processing an employee is actually 600+ lines and I need to execute that for multiple companies I split it out into the ProcessCompanyEmployee template. When I do that it doesn't like wd:SSN anymore. I assume I need to reference the wd:SSN, etc fields a different way, but I don't know what that is. Does that explain my issue better?

Comment: I got it to work by putting the `xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report_ABC"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element, or on both of the template declarations. Daniel Haley's answer is the most correct answer I'd say.

Comment: Thanks Geoff!  Both your's and Daniel Haley's ideas solved my problem.  Daniel's ran faster and like you said is probably better since it ends up only being in one place in the code.